# Why doesn't my setter warn that the property cannot be set?

Tags: php, extending-classes

In class `a` I have a `setter` defined. In class `b`, which extends class `a`, there is a `private` variable that the class `a` will therefore not be able to see. The `setter` in class `a` in this code will never set the variable `test` to a value different than the initial one, because it cannot reach it. If you run this code, for case A it will output `0`.

If you run case B however, you will get an `Exception` saying that the property `test2` does not exist.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

class a {
    public function __set($prop, $value) {
    if((!property_exists($this, $prop))) {
      $className = get_called_class();
      throw new Exception("The property `{$prop}` in `{$className}` does not exist");
    }
    $this->$prop = $value;
    return true;
  }
}

class b extends a {
    private $test = 0;

    public function getTest() {
        return $this->test;
    }
}

// Case A
$b = new b;
$b->test = 1;
echo $b->getTest();

// Case B
$b = new b;
$b->test2 = 2;
```

My question is, if the class `a` doesn't actually get to see the variable `test` and will not be able to set its value, why don't I get any kind of error, exception, warning or even a tiny little notice?

This is a situation that just happened to me in a real project and it was hard to find due to no error being generated and the code logically looking correct. So how do I prevent this kind of mistakes in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Since class `b` extends class `a`, it inherits the `__set()` method from class `a`. This means when you try and set a property on `b` it's `b` executing the `__set` code. You can test this out by echoing your `get_called_class()` value outside of the property exists

Comment: Then why doesn't case A echo `1`? Class `b` should have set its own private property to `1` and then echoed `1`, but instead it echoes `0`.

Comment: `__set` is only called when a property doesn't exist. Since `$test` is there, the class attempts to set the value without `__set` but can't as it's private

Comment: Well that's kind of what I said in my original post, but the question was in fact if I can do something to prevent these kinds of mistakes in the future, since there is no warning or exception being generated.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean sorry. Yeah, because you've used `__set()` you don't get the "Can't access private property $test" that you would if it weren't there. Therefore you'll need to test if the current classes $test property is private in the `__set()` method yourself. This is best done with the [Reflection properties](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)